# API versioning in Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm looking into .net core 6, API versioning and trying to show two versions "v1" and "v2" in swagger UI but only "v1" is showing though no error is appearing .

Here is my `program.cs` code

```
   builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(setup =>
    {
        setup.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1,0);
        setup.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        setup.ReportApiVersions = true;
    });

    builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
    {
        setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "API",
            Description = "An API in dotnet core 6",

        });
        var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine($@"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}", xmlFilename));
    });

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
```

v1 controller have this action method

```
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetLast12MonthBalances")]
    public async Task<ApiResponse> GetLast12MonthBalances()
    {
```

v2 controller have this action method

```
   [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
   [HttpGet,Route("GetLast12MonthBalances")]
   public async Task<ApiResponse> GetLast12MonthBalances()
   {
```

Any idea what is missing ?

Comment: Thanks, yes it helped though change some bit here

```[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Account/")]```
to this:

```[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure SwaggerGenOptions using options pattern.

1st- Create a class as follows:

```
namespace MyApi
{
    public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions
        : IConfigureNamedOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
    {
        private readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider;

        public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(
            IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
        {
            // add swagger document for every API version discovered
            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc(
                    description.GroupName, 
                    CreateVersionInfo(description));
            }
        }

        public void Configure(string name, SwaggerGenOptions options)
        {
            Configure(options);
        }

        private OpenApiInfo CreateVersionInfo(
                ApiVersionDescription description)
        {
            var info = new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "My API",
                Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString()
            };

            if (description.IsDeprecated)
            {
                info.Description += " deprecated API.";
            }

            return info;
        }
    }
}
```

2-wire up the options with the service collection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ITestsRepository, TestssRepository>();
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddApiVersioning(setup =>
    {
        setup.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        setup.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        setup.ReportApiVersions = true;
    });

    services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
    {
        setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

    services.AddSwaggerGen();
    services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still showing all version(v1 and v2) endpoints in one place and in swagger UI dropdown not showing v2 version for selection .

Comment: here is a complete guide hope it helps: https://referbruv.com/blog/integrating-aspnet-core-api-versions-with-swagger-ui/